# Strange behavior of deepcopy function in Python

Tags: python, deep-copy

I thought that if:

```
from copy import deepcopy

list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = deepcopy(list1)
```

then the id's must be like `id(list1) != id(list2)` and `id(list1[0]) != id(list2[0])`, but actually it behaves like:

```
id(list1) != id(list2)
```

yet

```
id(list1[0]) == id(list2[0])
```

Could anyone can explain this unusual behavior?

Comment: strings are immutable - no copying of the object is needed - just incrementing the reference count to the string itself... Try it with a mutable type and that will be copied...